# Using conditional to trigger a pull request workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 workflows below which runs on a pull request to staging. I only want workflow1 to run if the PR has dependency upgrade flag and workflow2 to run if the PR does not have dependency upgrade flag. How can I achieve this? sinnipet of my workflow is below

```
name: workflow1
on:
  pull_request:
   branches:
     - staging

jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Terragrunt Plan"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt init -ugrade

name: workflow2
on:
  pull_request:
   branches:
     - staging

jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Terragrunt Plan"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt init -lockfile=readonly
```